# Java SQL Exception Database is Locked

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

Can anyone help me fix the java `sql exception` database is `locked`.  When I clicked the `jtable` (`accounts_table`) and the data from this table goes to another `jtable` (`accounts_all`) and when I try to create new account by clicking the `jbutton` (`acct_create`) the database will open successfully but after that `JOptionPane` will show and the message in it is java sql exception database is `locked`.

```
private void acct_createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        int prompt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are those data correct?", "Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(prompt == 0){
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Edz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\bantug\\bantug_coop.sqlite");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opened database successfully");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String value2 = account_name.getText();
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE '"+(value2)+"' " +
                "(type CHAR, " + " account_number VARCHAR, " + " account_name VARCHAR, " + " home_address  VARCHAR, " + " telno_home  VARCHAR, " + " business_address  VARCHAR, " + " telno_business  VARCHAR, " + " initial_deposit  DOUBLE, " + " withdrawals  DOUBLE, " +" balance  DOUBLE, " +" posted_by  VARCHAR, " + " approved_by  VARCHAR, " + " date  DATETIME, " + " days  INT, " + " interest  DOUBLE, " + " interest_annum  DOUBLE, " + " member_type  CHAR, " + " fees  DOUBLE)";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                sql = "insert into '"+(value2)+"' (type, account_number, account_name, home_address, telno_home, business_address, telno_business, initial_deposit, posted_by, approved_by, date, days, interest, balance, member_type, fees) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                pst.setString(1, account_type.getText());
                pst.setString(2, account_number.getText());
                pst.setString(3, account_name.getText());
                pst.setString(4, account_home.getText());
                pst.setString(5, account_hometelno.getText());
                pst.setString(6, account_business.getText());
                pst.setString(7, account_bustelno.getText());
                pst.setString(8, account_deposit.getText());
                pst.setString(9, account_posted.getText());
                pst.setString(10, account_approved.getText());
                Date dateFromDateChooser = account_date.getDate();
                String dateString = String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td", dateFromDateChooser);
                pst.setString(11, dateString);
                pst.setInt(12, 0);
                double rateday = 0.03/360;
                double total = Double.parseDouble(account_deposit.getText());
                String deposit = df.format(new Double(total)).toString();
                double enter_value = new Integer(0);
                double total2 = total* rateday * enter_value;
                String total3= df.format(new Double(total2)).toString();
                pst.setString(13, total3);
                pst.setString(14, deposit);
                String value = member_type.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pst.setString(15, value);
                double fee = 0;
                String fee_int = new Double(fee).toString();
                pst.setString(16, fee_int);
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Data saved!");
                try{
                    sql = "select balance, days from '"+(value2)+"' where rowid = last_insert_rowid()";
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()){
                        try{
                            double withdraw = 0;
                            double sum = rs.getDouble("balance");
                            double days = rs.getDouble("days");
                            double amount = sum * rateday * days;
                            double sum_amount = sum+amount;
                            String new_amount = df.format(new Double(sum_amount)).toString();
                            sql = "update '"+(value2)+"' set interest_annum='"+new_amount+"', withdrawals='"+withdraw+"' where rowid = last_insert_rowid()";
                            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                            pst.execute();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Interest data saved!");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                        }finally{
                            try{
                                rs.close();
                                pst.close();
                            }catch(Exception e){

                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                    //for pbook printing data
                    sql = "select *  from '"+value2+"' where rowid = last_insert_rowid()";
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()){
                        String with = rs.getString("withdrawals");
                        pbook_with.setText(with);
                        String dep = rs.getString("initial_deposit");
                        pbook_dep.setText(dep);
                        if(with == "0" && dep == "0"){
                            type_trnscn.setText("wthdrw");
                        }else if(with != "0" && dep != "0"){
                            type_trnscn.setText("dep");
                        }
                        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        if(((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("3-31")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("6-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("9-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("12-31")){
                            String inter = rs.getString("interest");
                            pbook_interest.setText(inter);
                        }else if(((month+1)+"-"+day)!="3-31"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="6-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="9-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="12-31"){                    
                            pbook_interest.setText("0");
                        }
                        sql  = "select sum(initial_deposit), sum(withdrawals), interest_annum from '"+value2+"'";
                        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                        rs = pst.executeQuery();
                        if(rs.next()){
                            if(((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("3-31")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("6-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("9-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("12-31")){
                                String adb = rs.getString("interest_annum");
                                pbook_bal.setText(adb);
                            }else if(((month+1)+"-"+day)!="3-31"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="6-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="9-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="12-31"){                    
                                String sumdep = rs.getString("sum(initial_deposit)");
                                String sumwith = rs.getString("sum(withdrawals)");
                                double depval = Double.parseDouble(sumdep);
                                double withval = Double.parseDouble(sumwith);
                                double value_amount = depval-withval;
                                String total_amount = Double.toString(value_amount);
                                pbook_bal.setText(total_amount);
                            }
                        }                
                    }
                    sql = "select rowid as 'Account ID', type as 'Type', account_number as 'Account No.', account_name as 'Account Name', home_address as 'Home Address', telno_home as 'Tel. No. Home', business_address as 'Business Address', telno_business as 'Business Tel. No.', initial_deposit as 'Deposit',  withdrawals as 'Withdrawals', balance as 'Balance', posted_by as 'Posted By', approved_by as 'Approved By', date as 'Date', days as 'No. of Days', interest as 'Interest per ADB', interest_annum as 'Total Balance', member_type as 'Membership Type', fees as 'Charges'  from '"+value2+"'";
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    accounts_all.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    accounts_all.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                    try{//add data to Savings Table
                            sql = "select *  from '"+value2+"' where rowid = last_insert_rowid()";
                            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                            rs = pst.executeQuery();
                            if(rs.next()){
                                String type = rs.getString("type");
                                String no = rs.getString("account_number");
                                String name = rs.getString("account_name");
                                String h_add = rs.getString("home_address");
                                String h_tel = rs.getString("telno_home");
                                String b_add = rs.getString("business_address");
                                String b_tel = rs.getString("telno_business");
                                String i_dep = rs.getString("initial_deposit");
                                String withdraw = rs.getString("withdrawals");
                                String bal = rs.getString("balance");
                                String post = rs.getString("posted_by");
                                String approved = rs.getString("approved_by");                                
                                String date = rs.getString("date");
                                String days = rs.getString("days");
                                String interest = rs.getString("interest");
                                String int_annum = rs.getString("interest_annum");
                                String member_type = rs.getString("member_type");
                                String c_fee = rs.getString("fees");
                                String acct_code = new Integer(21100).toString();
                                sql = "insert into Savings (acct_code,type,date,member_type,account_number,account_name,home_address,telno_home,business_address,telno_business,initial_deposit,posted_by,approved_by,days,interest,balance,interest_annum,withdrawals,fees) values ('"+acct_code+"', '"+type+"', '"+date+"', '"+member_type+"', '"+no+"', '"+name+"', '"+h_add+"', '"+h_tel+"', '"+b_add+"', '"+b_tel+"', '"+i_dep+"', '"+post+"', '"+approved+"', '"+days+"', '"+interest+"', '"+bal+"', '"+int_annum+"', '"+withdraw+"', '"+c_fee+"')";
                                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                                pst.execute();
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Savings Data Saved");
                                sql = "insert into Savings_Master (acct_code,type,date,member_type,account_number,account_name,home_address,telno_home,business_address,telno_business,initial_deposit,posted_by,approved_by,days,interest,balance,interest_annum,withdrawals,fees) values ('"+acct_code+"', '"+type+"', '"+date+"', '"+member_type+"', '"+no+"', '"+name+"', '"+h_add+"', '"+h_tel+"', '"+b_add+"', '"+b_tel+"', '"+i_dep+"', '"+post+"', '"+approved+"', '"+days+"', '"+interest+"', '"+bal+"', '"+int_annum+"', '"+withdraw+"', '"+c_fee+"')";
                                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                                pst.execute();
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Savings Master Data saved");
                            }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }finally{
                        try{
                            rs.close();
                            pst.close();
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    System.exit(0);
                }finally{
                    try{
                        rs.close();
                        pst.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
                UpdateTable();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                System.exit(0);
            }finally{
                try{
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table created successfully");

        }
    }
```

and here is the `jtable` code:

```
private void accounts_tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
        try{//print p_book data
            int row = accounts_table.getSelectedRow();
            String table_click = (accounts_table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            String sql = "select * from '"+table_click+"' order by rowid DESC limit 1";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                String with = rs.getString("withdrawals");
                pbook_with.setText(with);
                String dep = rs.getString("initial_deposit");
                pbook_dep.setText(dep);
                if(with == "0" && dep == "0"){
                    type_trnscn.setText("wthdrw");
                }else if(with != "0" && dep != "0"){
                    type_trnscn.setText("dep");
                }
                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                if(((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("3-31")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("6-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("9-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("12-31")){
                    String inter = rs.getString("interest");
                    pbook_interest.setText(inter);
                }else if(((month+1)+"-"+day)!="3-31"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="6-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="9-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="12-31"){                    
                    pbook_interest.setText("0");
                }
                sql  = "select sum(initial_deposit), sum(withdrawals), interest_annum from '"+table_click+"'";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    if(((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("3-31")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("6-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("9-30")||((month+1)+"-"+day).matches("12-31")){
                        String adb = rs.getString("interest_annum");
                        pbook_bal.setText(adb);
                    }else if(((month+1)+"-"+day)!="3-31"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="6-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="9-30"||((month+1)+"-"+day)!="12-31"){                    
                        String sumdep = rs.getString("sum(initial_deposit)");
                        String sumwith = rs.getString("sum(withdrawals)");
                        double depval = Double.parseDouble(sumdep);
                        double withval = Double.parseDouble(sumwith);
                        double value = depval-withval;
                        String total = Double.toString(value);
                        pbook_bal.setText(total);
                    }
                }                
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
        try{
            int row = accounts_table.getSelectedRow();
            String table_click = (accounts_table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            String sql = "select rowid as 'Account ID', type as 'Type', account_number as 'Account No.', account_name as 'Account Name', home_address as 'Home Address', telno_home as 'Tel. No. Home', business_address as 'Business Address', telno_business as 'Business Tel. No.', initial_deposit as 'Deposit',  withdrawals as 'Withdrawals', balance as 'Balance',posted_by as 'Posted By', approved_by as 'Approved By', date as 'Date', days as 'No. of Days', interest as 'Interest per ADB', interest_annum as 'ADB', member_type as 'Type of Member', fees as 'Charges'  from '"+table_click+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            accounts_all.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            accounts_all.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            int index = 0;
            while (index < 19){
                if(index == 0){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(70);
                }else if(index == 1){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(70);
                }else if(index == 2){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(150);
                }else if(index == 3){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(200);
                }else if(index == 4){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(300);
                }else if(index == 5){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(150);
                }else if(index == 6){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(300);
                }else if(index == 7){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(150);
                }else if(index == 8){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(250);
                }else if(index == 9){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(200);
                }else if(index == 10){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(200);
                }else if(index == 11){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(150);
                }else if(index == 12){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(90);
                }else if(index == 13){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(100);
                }else if(index == 14){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(100);
                }else if(index == 15){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(100);
                }else if(index == 16){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(100);
                }else if(index == 17){
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(100);
                }else{
                    TableColumn ut =accounts_all.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    ut.setPreferredWidth(150);
                }
                index+=1;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
        UpdateTable();
    }
```

and here is my sql connection code:

```
public class sqlconnect {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnectorDb(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Edz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\bantug\\bantug_coop.sqlite");
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception and its stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to create new account by clicking the jbutton (acct_create)
>   the database will open successfully but after that JOptionPane will
>   show and the message in it is java sql exception database is locked.

You need to close connection in all cases before open new. Please start debug your code in this case and add debug point to finaly block and to

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Edz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\bantug\\bantug_coop.sqlite");
```

**EDIT:** I don't see when cases call your `sqlconnect` class. May be created one connection in `createActionPerformed` method and not closed it before call sqlconnect or vice versa. I offer to add one check before created connenction. For example:

```
if(conn!=null && conn.isClosed()){
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Edz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\bantug\\bantug_coop.sqlite");
}
```

Could you try it?

Comment: can you tell me the proper way to debug? I did debug on my code in netbeans but still the problem exist.

Comment: I have also written this code on my every try catch block to close th connection: }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

Comment: No. I mean add one debug point to start `acct_createActionPerformed`method and second to `sqlconnect` or `accounts_tableMouseClicked` method. You fine described when you get this exception. So you know which block occured this problem in `accounts_tableMouseClicked` method.

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem with your account, your username password.
If you exceed maximum number of reattempts to logon to a DB then account gets locked.

So check your account password.

Comment: is there maximum limit of account password?

Comment: can you tell me what to do to fix the problem?

Comment: You shld check your password and correct it. Check with your password if you are able to connect to DB from SQL client.

Comment: I am using sqlite and I have no password to connect on my DB.

Comment: Seems I can connect properly on my DB

Comment: I can connect properly to my DB can you tell me how to fix this.